# Hiding rows based on a cell's value

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop

I'm trying to hide rows on a several sheets (the same row numbers) based on a particular cell's value.

I have the cell value reference working and not included here, but I can't get the For Each code to work with my Dim.

```
Sub ThisOneWorks()
   
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim InputSheets As Variant
    Set InputSheets = Worksheets(Array("Incurred", "PO Values", "Estimates"))

    Dim y2019 As Range
    Set y2019 = Range("6:57").EntireRow
    
    For Each ws In InputSheets
        ws.Range("6:57").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    Next
 
End Sub
```

See the second to last line for what's changed.

```
Sub DoesNotWork()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim InputSheets As Variant
    Set InputSheets = Worksheets(Array("Incurred", "PO Values", "Estimates"))
    
    Dim y2019 As Range
    Set y2019 = Range("6:57").EntireRow
    
    For Each ws In InputSheets
        ws.y2019.EntireRow.Hidden = True
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: You are trying to set a range to use in a loop which will not work since a range is a property of the `Worksheet` object. You have to set the `Range` for each specific sheet which is what I am doing inside the loop. Once you set the range, the worksheet is constant and will not change, even if you nest it inside the loop. Your statement `ws.y2019` is a invalid call because the range `y2019` already has a worksheet assigned to it. If you sub everything in you are really saying something like `Sheet(A).Sheet(B).y2019` which is nonsensical of course.

Comment: This makes a lot of sense, thank you! So there is no way to define a range as a Dim for multiple sheets! I will need to define the range per sheet then. I think that will work - it may be a lot of copy and paste but I think it will work, or at least i understand that.

Comment: Does each sheet have it's own set of rows that need to be hidden? You could create a 2d array that stores both sheet & rows of interest and sub the variables in accordingly. These variables would be strings, not objects (much like the sheet name here - you are using strings to build objects)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are confusing a `Worksheet` loop for a `String` loop which is what you have here:

```
Sub Try_This()

Dim InputSheets: InputSheets = Array("Incurred", "PO Values", "Estimates")
Dim i As Long

For i = LBound(InputSheets) To UBound(InputSheets)
    Sheets(InputSheets(i)).Rows("6:57").Hidden = True
Next i

End Sub
```

---

### EDIT

Same thing but with `Range` variable to hide the rows instead of a direct call

```
Dim InputSheets: InputSheets = Array("Sheet2", "Sheet3", "Sheet4")
Dim Y2019 As Range, i as Long

For i = LBound(InputSheets) To UBound(InputSheets)
    Set Y2019 = Sheets(InputSheets(i)).Rows("6:57")
    Y2019.Hidden = True
Next i
```

Comment: This work, but in the same capacity as my original code. Once I try to:
`Set y2019 = `
and replace it in the `For` statement it stops working. Any thoughts? 

I have lots of ranges of rows that represent years and I want to use this naming as it will be easier to follow.

Comment: Updated to show correct way to dynamically `Set` a range object. You must re-assign the range inside the loop for each sheet accordingly. You cannot just append a range with a new worksheet the way you are trying to

Comment: I'm not sure I'm asking my questions correctly, so apologies for this. Thank you for your response they are really insightful but I still can't figure out my main issue. I want to set the `row` range. This loop is nested in an `if` statement and this will result in me needing to `set` this in each one of these statements. Is there a better way to `set` the row range than how i'm doing this?

Comment: You are talking about creating variables to contain the actual rows. You could store that as a `String` variable and then place it inside the `Rows` function if you needed. But no, you cannot `SET` a range to work the way you want. Note there is a difference between `SETTING` & `ASSIGNING A VALUE`. You `Set` objects and `Assign` values. If you are not getting your point across, try adding more examples becuase right now it looks like this is what you need. Sometimes pictures help to clear up things that are hard to explain